# Mirrored display, mouse cursor missing

Tags: mouse, hdmi, ubuntu-14.04, mirroring, mouse-cursor

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 connected via HDMI to a TV.
After the computer comes back from suspend the mirrored desktop on the TV display sometimes doesn't show the mouse cursor.

The only way I found to solve this is by going to Settings->Display and turn off/on the Mirror check box.

How can I solve this issue without the need to go to Setting every time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a very common problem with Ubuntu 14.

Upon looking around, I have something that might help.

First off, is the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

This seems to be the command that will restore the cursor, however, it is quite long and difficult to memorize. Now lets make a "short-cut"!

## Bash: Linux's Swiss Army Knife

So lets make a quick bash script that will get you running quickly this problem arises. Type `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false` in a new file in your "Home" folder. name the file something like `c.sh` or another name that is easy to remember.

Now we just have to set the executable bit for it. Open a terminal, (I am assuming the file is`c.sh` and is in your "Home" folder) and type `chmod +x c.sh` This will allow the system to run the file.

Now next time this happens just use the keybard short-cut, `Alt+F2` to open an execute window, and type `~/c.sh` This will hopefully be a quick easy fix for this problem.

Note, however, there seem to be many things that cause this problem, so this answer may or may not work for you. Let me know if this works.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Or add `#!/bin/bash` above that `gsettings` commnd, so you can just save the file as `c` and run `./c` and maybe copy it to somewhere in your path so you can just do `c`. Another option is to make an alias by adding `alias c="gsettings set  to org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false" to your `.bashrc`™

Comment: I thought this works, but it doesn't. It seems the command has zero effect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter the gconf setting which alters this behavior, e.g. from a command line (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

    `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false`

The cool thing is if you can do it from the command line, you can automate it with scripts or other tools!

One option is to make a [Ubuntu desktop shortcut](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) which you can then simply double-click when you want it to "go".Create a new file on your desktop `mousy.desktop`. Edit this file to include the contents shown here:

    `[Desktop Entry]
    Name=mousy
    Comment=restore my mouse
    Icon=utilities-terminal
    Exec=gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
    Terminal=false
    Type=Application`

And add execute permissions (`chmod +x mousy`) and the icon displayed should change appearance and you can now double-click it to run the command you added via editing the file.

To confirm this worked, enter the following in a terminal:

    `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active`

and the terminal should print "false" (or whatever value the command in your file says).

Comment: doesn't work. The command has zero effect. Maybe something should be called to use this new setting?

Comment: Hmmm... let me look into it some more. It was difficult to find a setting relating to the "mirror check box" you described. `gsettings` ought to be one way to do it, though.

Comment: Have you tried using `dconf-editor` to browse for the available settings? `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

Comment: Maybe also look for new content in `/var/log/messages` or another syslog to help find some clues to why the mirror has effect.

Comment: Try it with `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr default-monitors-setup clone`... this was the closest other setting in dconf-editor I could find, with the description: "Whether to turn off specific monitors after boot".

Comment: Any luck trying this?

Comment: Sorry, no luck. Nothing happens. Maybe there is no way to control this from command line :/

Comment: I would have to think there is; it's just a matter of finding the right interface (i.e. not `gsettings`, apparently).

Comment: I'll continue the research. Thanks for trying :)

Comment: Maybe something in xrandr or xorg configuration files. Those are topics I'm learning more about, too.